# Objective-c variable initialization problem

Tags: objective-c

I have a header file variable.h where i declare all my global variable.Then i add this header file my wordgame.m .Here i have 
several function .The problem is that when i initialize some global (int) variable in a function other function do no get the initialized value.Other function always displayed value(=100)
for these variable.Even if i do not initialize them they always display value 100.Can any one tell me what is the problem???
As far as i know in objective-c uninitialized variable default value is 0.So why my global variable display value 100.

Comment: Post some example code where you are having a problem.

Comment: You need to post some of the code, but I will say that globals are not guaranteed to be initialized to 0. Instance variables are after you alloc the object, but not globals.

Comment: Infact the initialization problem occurs in my I-phone,not in simulator.when I run the code in my i-phone the following messege
displayed:-
<br>
warning: Unable to read symbols for ""/Users/riseuppromotions/Desktop/ modified game/wordmaking/build/Release-iphoneos"/wordmaking.app/wordmaking" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for ""/Users/riseuppromotions/Desktop/ modified game/wordmaking/build/Release-iphoneos"/wordmaking.app/wordmaking" (file not found).
</br> 
is this  the reason???
my code is too bigg to send.
Plz give me some explation about this warning and what to do.

Comment: Louis: everything except for union globals are guaranteed to be initialized to 0 (if no initializer is present). With unions, it is only the first named member that is guaranteed to be zeroed.

Comment: On a site like Stack Overflow the quality of answers you get is proportional to the quality of effort you put in. You've asked 14 questions, never marked answer as correct or up or down voted a single answer, and then aren't willing to do any work to post the variable declaration and some of the surrounding context so that people might be able to help you. Why should we put in any work trying to solve your problems when you aren't willing to put in a basic effort to try to describe them clearly?

Comment: Chris: Fair enough, I thought that was OS dependent behaviour since the data section was always laid down on zero-filled pages to prevent information leakage, but C99 §6.7.8.10 effectively guarantees it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have all your globals in one file, variable.h, such as

```
int global1, global2;
char shortStr[32];
```

And `#include` or `#import` this into each of your files, then you are creating unique globals in each of these files, independent of and unrelated to each other.

So, if you change the value of global1 in one file, wordgame.m, it would only be that global1 that has been changed, not the global1 in another .m file.

A better way to do this would be to have, in your variable.h:

```
extern int global1, global2;
extern char shortStr[32];
```

and in the most relevant .m file, you have:

```
int global1;
```

and in another .m file, you'll have:

```
int global2;
char shortStr[32];
```

Now, any file that has the variable.h included, will be able to access these globals, and there will be just one instance of these globals, so any value in these globals will be the same across all files.

Better way to do this would be not use globals at all, and use classes, singletons, and delegates...

Comment: Although my problem is not because of what u describe(as all of my function is in a single .m file), i learnt a important thing from your answer,which i did not know.so thank u very much.